# How to view call stack with dtrace

Tags: c, solaris, dtrace

How to view call stack, return value and arguments of the simply program below, with **dtrace**

```
 /** Trival code **/

 #include <stdio.h>

 int
 foo (int *a, int *b)
 {
     *a = *b;
     *b = 4;
     return 0;
 }  

 int
 main (void)
 {
     int a, b;
     a = 1;
     b = 2;
     foo (&a, &b);
     printf ("Value a: %d, Value b: %d\n", a, b); 
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, here's the script:

```
pid$target::foo:entry
{
    ustack();

    self->arg0 = arg0;
    self->arg1 = arg1;

    printf("arg0 = 0x%x\n", self->arg0);
    printf("*arg0 = %d\n", *(int *)copyin(self->arg0, 4));

    printf("arg1 = 0x%x\n", self->arg1);
    printf("*arg1 = %d\n", *(int *)copyin(self->arg1, 4));
}

pid$target::foo:return
{
    ustack();
    printf("arg0 = 0x%x\n", self->arg0);
    printf("*arg0 = %d\n", *(int *)copyin(self->arg0, 4));

    printf("arg1 = 0x%x\n", self->arg1);
    printf("*arg1 = %d\n", *(int *)copyin(self->arg1, 4));

    printf("return = %d\n", arg1);
}
```

How this works.  ustack() prints the stack of the user process.

In an function entry, argN is the Nth argument to the function.  Since the arguments are
pointers, you need to use copyin() to copy in the actual data before you dereference it.

For a function return, you no longer have access to the function arguments.  So you save
the parameters for later use.

Finally, for a function return, you can access the value returned by the function with
arg1.

Comment: Actually, reading the args at entry time can cause errors because the memory address might have not been paged in yet.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcgkk.html#gcgkr